# Flutter ImagePicker - Getting image asynchronously in onPressed shows lint warning

Tags: flutter, async-await, flutter-onpressed

I am implementing a profile picture upload with `ImagePicker` and put the logic into the `onPressed` function of a button like this:

```
    OutlinedButton.icon(
      icon: Icon(Icons.upload),
      label: Text("Select profile picture"),
      onPressed: () async {
        XFile? image = await introVM.imagePicker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery,
            imageQuality: 50,
            preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front);
        if (image != null) introVM.setProfilePicture(image!.path);
      },
    );
```

Everything works fine without errors, but I am getting a lint warning about the `async` part:

> Expected a sync function but got async.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Dart Code Metrics, it is a warning for a Dart code design that avoids calling an asynchronous function where a synchronous is expected.

[avoid-passing-async-when-sync-expected](https://dartcodemetrics.dev/docs/rules/common/avoid-passing-async-when-sync-expected)

To avoid complaints from linting, there are 2 ways for now.

1. use then() method

```dart
OutlinedButton.icon(
    icon: Icon(Icons.upload),
    label: Text("Select profile picture"),
    onPressed: () {
        introVM.imagePicker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery, 
            imageQuality: 50,
            preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front
        ).then((XFile? xFile) {
             if (xFile != null) introVM.setProfilePicture(xFile!.path);
        });
    },
);
```

2. Use the anonymous function (I am not preferred that one, and we should convert it into a separate function)

```dart
OutlinedButton.icon(
    icon: Icon(Icons.upload),
    label: Text("Select profile picture"),
    onPressed: () {
        // Should move to a separate function
        () async {
            XFile? image = await introVM.imagePicker.pickImage(
                source: ImageSource.gallery,
                imageQuality: 50,
                preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front);
            if (image != null) introVM.setProfilePicture(image!.path);
         };
    },
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it when I'm home and accept your answer if it works. One question: so I would rewrite this simply to get rid of the warning, but there is no actual functional/safety difference between the `async` and `.then()` version, correct?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. And, one more thing, we can look at the lint rule and put it in the analysis_options.yaml file in order to get rid of the warning.